# Emacs wsl grep fails on special characters

Tags: grep, wsl

I'm using GNU Emacs 26.3 on a Windows 10 system (Virtualbox guest on Mac).

The following grep command inside emacs fails:

```
grep -i -n -d skip -e temp_ *
```

with this error:

```
grep -i -n -d skip -e temp_ * NUL
agrep: NUL: No such file or directory

Grep exited abnormally with code 2 at Mon Mar 23 12:27:03
```

If I run the command in the `wsl` shell it works.
The following grep command inside emacs also works fine:

```
grep -i -n -d skip -e temp *
```

*Note:* the missing _ at the end.

I tried escaping the underscore with `\` and `\\`, nothing helped.

Any ideas?  Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** FYI: I'm using the following shell command, which works fine for other grep, make, etc. commands:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe")
(setq shell-file-name explicit-shell-file-name)
```

**as for Tobias request:**
I run the 'grep command via my shortcut F5:

```
(global-set-key [f5] 'grep)
```

then:

```
Run grep (like this): grep -i -n -d skip -e temp_ *
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inside emacs"? How do you run the command? Please give the key sequence you use before typing the shell command or the major mode of the buffer you are in when typing the shell command. Maybe, you can even give a recipe for reproducing the problem starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: I start the emacs using: runemacs.exe.
So I did not really manage of invoking grep via command line runemacs -Q

Comment: AFAIK `explicit-shell-file-name` has nothing to do with `grep`. What is the value of `shell-file-name` that is really used?

Comment: I added the 2nd command which I use, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: From my point of view it is a bit awkward to use the WSL version of bash when you are <stroke>within WSL</stroke> -- no actually you are in Ubuntu or whatever Linux Distro you chose in your WSL settings. Why don't you keep the default settings? Comment out the settings for `explicit-shell-file-name` and `shell-file-name` restart Emacs and try again. I assume that `/bin/sh` is used in that case. If you want bash syntax you could set `explicit-shell-file-name` to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: If I remove evertyhing from my .emacs or if I use emacs -Q I have this:
shell-file-name is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is
"C:/Program Files (x86)/emacs/libexec/emacs/26.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe"
-- So it is not working I get a 
"'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: Ah, you are using the mingw-version of Emacs. That is a completely different story. You should add the output of `M-x emacs-version` to the question. Note that I am using the WSL Ubuntu-version of Emacs which works very fine for me.

Comment: You are right: "GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-08-29"
I didn't even know the wsl version exists.  Is this the one: https://github.com/hubisan/emacs-wsl ?
Maybe you want to post the link as answer, so I can accept it.  Thanks a lot so far :)

Comment: I do not know how familiar you are with Linux. If you aren't you should stick to the mingw Emacs. If you are familiar with Linux just install Emacs in the bash-shell with `apt-get` or anything similar. In that case you probably also want an appropriate X-server, as e.g., [Vxsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) which is installed under Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@Tobias](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2370/tobias) valuable feedback it is now working.  See the comments above for details.  Here is the **summary**:

I was using the mingw-version of Emacs (means the windows version of emacs).  Now I installed an X-Server and emacs in my wsl Ubuntu shell and now use this emacs instead.  And the problem no longer occurs.